# Rotate effect on diamonds

Tags: jquery, html

I have a diamond on page, my diamond created with css properties.i want after page load Complete, diamond animate.
Is there any solution for this?
This is my code [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Pp5SF/11/)

Answer (score 2):

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/WhZym/715/

You need to add the CSS `transition-duration` property

CSS:

```
.rotate {
    background: #F02311;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font: normal 1em Arial;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 5s;
}
```

and then also add the rotation of `360`

Comment: Have you got your answer?

Comment: No. I want to rotate the object in place. Like this sample http://thedrawingroomcreative.com

Answer (score 0):

you can put your code for load Complete here :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //place for page load Complete code
}
);
```